# Laravel Route Can Not Find By Route Name

Tags: laravel, routes

This is My Route

```
Route::namespace("Core\Controller\Site")
        ->prefix("/")
        ->name("site.")
        ->group(function () {
 Route::get("{slug}", "NewsController@index")->name("news.index");
            Route::get("show/{slug}", "NewsController@show")->name("news.show");
            Route::get("{slug}", "ArticleController@index")->name("article.index");
            Route::get("show/{slug}", "ArticleController@show")->name("article.show");
            Route::get("{slug}", "VideoController@index")->name("video.index");       
});
```

This is My a href which is I used This Route

```
<a href="{{ route('site.news.show', $item->slug) }}"></a>
```

It gives Such Kind Of Error

```
Route [site.news.show] not defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same route paths `(show/{slug} and {slug})` with the same methods for different route names.
I think they override each other. Try to use different route paths.

Answer (score 1):

change the name of the route and it will work.

`show_news and show_article`

```
Route::namespace("Core\Controller\Site")
        ->prefix("/")
        ->name("site.")
        ->group(function () {
 Route::get("{slug}", "NewsController@index")->name("news.index");
            Route::get("show_news/{slug}", "NewsController@show")->name("news.show");
            Route::get("{slug}", "ArticleController@index")->name("article.index");
            Route::get("show_article/{slug}", "ArticleController@show")->name("article.show");
            Route::get("{slug}", "VideoController@index")->name("video.index");       
});
```